# SP2010 Calendar Web Part removed from page on check in

Tags: 2010, web-part, calendar

I have a page which has hosted a calendar web part almost since the page was created. Today a user notified me the calendar was missing from the page. I have tried adding the web part back onto the page and it all goes well until I check the page in and the web part disappears.

I have since tried creating a new page and I get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the Calendar Web Part into a Web Part Zone? If it's being added outside of a Web Part Zone, then it will be deleted when you "Reattach to Page Layout", and this may be what you're experiencing. Note that this would only come up if you are working through SharePoint Designer, whereas if you're making the changes as a Power User then this should not be an issue.